# jquery - remove specific element from cloned node

Tags: jquery

Im trying to clone tree, remove one element from it and then append result to new place. But the problem is that element is not deleted, it always append original tree.

```
$(".js-parent-trigger").click(function() {        
    var commentForm = $("#js-add-comment-wrapper").clone(true).css("margin", "10px").remove(".js-add-comment-title");
    $(this).parents(".js-comment-wrapper").append(commentForm);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @aSeptik - you can work with elements before they are appended.

Comment: patrick, your answer was correct, why you deleted it?

Comment: I deleted because I thought I had made a mistake. I didn't realize you could use `.remove()` with a selector, so I was doing a little research to see what element was being returned. Back online now. :)

Comment: @patrick - sure you can remove something from cloned object!?

Comment: @aSeptik - Absolutely :o) http://jsfiddle.net/USHQU/

Comment: @patrick - you are great bro! ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(".js-parent-trigger").click(function() {        
    var commentForm = $("#js-add-comment-wrapper").clone(true).css("margin", "10px");
    commentForm.find(".js-add-comment-title").remove();
    $(this).parents(".js-comment-wrapper").append(commentForm);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't help making it one big statement:

```
$(".js-parent-trigger").click(function() {        
   $("#js-add-comment-wrapper").clone(true).css("margin", "10px")
         .find(".js-add-comment-title").remove()
         .end().appendTo('.js-commet-wrapper');
    return false;
});
```